# Flex Compiler Error 1120

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, compiler-errors

I know there are a million questions on the web regarding the AS3 compiler error `1120: Access of undefined property <property>`, but this case is just weird.

I am skinning an `<s:Application>` component in Flex 4.6, and I am within the skin MXML file. The line `super.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, positionObjects);` is giving me issues saying: `1120: Access of undefined property positionObjects`. However `positionObjects` is declared right underneath it. Any idea what's wrong?

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, 
            unscaledHeight:Number) : void
        {
            bgRectFill.color = getStyle('backgroundColor');
            bgRectFill.alpha = getStyle('backgroundAlpha');
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }

    //Listen for when objects are added to the stage, before positioning them
        [Bindable]
        private var logoX:Number = 0;

        super.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, positionObjects);

        private function positionObjects(e:Event):void {
            this.logoX = stage.stageWidth / 3;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I was getting an error. I wasn't thinking and assuming that I could add an event listener outside of an initialization handler. I was, for some reason, thinking that AS3 would run through the compiled `<fx:Script>` tag the way interpreters execute procedural scripts.

I didn't think, again, for some reason, to add an `addedToStage` attribute to the `<s:Skin>` tag, and have it execute the `positionObjects` method from there. All is well now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have executable implementation within the `fx:Script` block like:

```
<fx:Script>
    super.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, positionObjects);
</fx:Script>
```

This should be called from a lifecycle function such as creation complete:

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
        alpha.disabled="0.5"
        alpha.disabledWithControlBar="0.5"
        creationComplete="skin1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[

            /* your implementation, same as before... */

            protected function skin1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // move your event listener to this function.
                super.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, positionObjects);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Skin>
```

Comment: Yep, thank you. I just answered my own question a few seconds before. +1